# How to add a border to an image

Tags: vb.net

This is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
  Public TheImage As Image = PictureBox1.BackgroundImage
  Public Function AppendBorder(ByVal original As Image, ByVal borderWidth As Integer) As Image
    Dim borderColor As Color = Color.Red
    Dim mypen As New Pen(borderColor, borderWidth * 2)
    Dim newSize As Size = New Size(original.Width + borderWidth * 2, original.Height + borderWidth * 2)
    Dim img As Bitmap = New Bitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)

    ' g.Clear(borderColor)
    g.DrawImage(original, New Point(borderWidth, borderWidth))
    g.DrawRectangle(mypen, 0, 0, newSize.Width, newSize.Height)
    g.Dispose()
    Return img
  End Function

  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim OutputImage As Image = AppendBorder(TheImage, 2)
    PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = OutputImage
  End Sub
End Class
```

There is an actual background image centered inside `PictureBox1`, which I added in the Designer. But when I debug, I get the error message:

> InvalidOperationException was unhandled

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Public TheImage As Image = PictureBox1.BackgroundImage
```

That cannot work.  PictureBox1 doesn't yet have a value when this statement executes, that doesn't happen until the InitializeComponent() method runs.  You probably never heard about that yet, the magic incantation is you typing "Public Sub New".  When you press enter then you'll see this:

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
```

That's the *constructor*, a very important part of a .NET class.  Note the "Add any initialization" comment that was generated.  That's where you initialize TheImage.  To make it look like this:

```
Public TheImage As Image

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    TheImage = PictureBox1.BackgroundImage
End Sub
```

If this is all still mysterious then hit the books to learn more.

Comment: You've just beaten me by 11 seconds on this one. :)

Comment: Thanks Hans. You're right... even though I've been coding in VB for a few years, I didn't know about that. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code:

```
Public TheImage As Image = PictureBox1.BackgroundImage
```

Initializes `TheImage` before `InitializeComponent` is called, so `PictureBox1` is not yet created at this point. When I moved this piece into a `Form_Load`, everything worked perfectly:

```
Public TheImage As Image
'...
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  TheImage = PictureBox1.BackgroundImage
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice to know about another way to do it. Thanks!